VueJS/Vue Router/Firebase - router.push() loads new page temporarily, then immediatley goes back to the Register page
I have a page that allows a user to register an account. Upon clicking submit, the user should be redirected to a Library page. However, what is happening is the Library page will flash on the screen for a second, then the Register page shows up again.
This is the RegisterPage.vue


import { ref } from 'vue'
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const email = ref('')
const password = ref('')
const router = useRouter()

const register = () => {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email.value, password.value)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Succesfully Registgered')
      router.push('/library', { shallow: true })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.code)
      alert(error.message)
    })
}
const signInWithGoogle = () => {}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.5.1/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <h1>Create and Account</h1>
      <input type="email" placeholder="user@mail.com" v-model="email" required />
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" v-model="password" required />
      <button @click="register">Register</button>
      <button @click="signInWithGoogle">Sign in with Google</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>



Looking at the register() method, he user is successfully registered in the Firebase console, and the console.log successfully posts the message, so i know the method works. I just cant figure out why the Library page only loads for a second, then reverts back to the Register page.
index.ts


import HomePage from '@/views/HomePage.vue'
import LibraryPage from '@/views/LibraryPage.vue'
import RegisterPage from '@/views/RegisterPage.vue'
import SignInPage from '@/views/SignInPage.vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomePage,
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: RegisterPage,
    },
    {
      path: '/sign-in',
      name: 'sign-in',
      component: SignInPage,
    },
    {
      path: '/library',
      name: 'library',
      component: LibraryPage,
    },
  ],
})

export default router
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.5.1/vue.global.min.js"></script>



Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please, provide a way to reproduce, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This won't happen under normal circumstances. This could happen if Library contains a redirect or there are route hooks that can do this, this is not shown. You should be able to replace firebase with any asynchronous action for this purpose. It's unclear what's the purpose of { shallow: true }
